# ActiveMQ onmessage is blocked when other consumer is processing message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.6. I have two consumer. When one consumer receive message on onmessage method, other consumer is not receiving message. means I want 2nd consumer to be able to receive second message during computation of first one.
I tried  many thing but nothing is working..

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(user, password, url);
connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(true);

connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Session session1 = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destinationQueue1 = session.createQueue(dataQ);
Destination destinationQueue2 = session1.createQueue(dataQ);
NormalListener listener = new NormalListener();
NormalListener listener2 = new NormalListener();
MessageConsumer consumerData1 = session.createConsumer(destinationQueue1);
consumerData1.setMessageListener(listner1);

MessageConsumer consumerData2 = session1.createConsumer(destinationQueue2);
consumerData2.setMessageListener(listener2);




public class NormalListener  implements MessageListener{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    String receivedMessage=textMessage.getText();
                    readMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code creates two sessions - session and session1 - and only uses the first one (session) to create the consumers.

Try to create the first consumer using the first session, and the second consumer using the second session. I also would use consistent naming, using session1 and session2:

```
MessageConsumer consumerData1 = session1.createConsumer(destinationQueue1);
consumerData1.setMessageListener(listner1);

MessageConsumer consumerData2 = session2.createConsumer(destinationQueue2);
consumerData2.setMessageListener(listener2);
```

---

NormalListener is not a standard JMS class / interface. Can you try a normal MessageListener instead?

Also you are not showing the code within the onMessage() method of the message listeners. Did you check it for potential threading issues, and reduce their code to a minimum for testing?

See also: http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html

Comment: Thanks mjn for your reply. I change session1 to session2. But problem is again same.

Comment: can you please also tell me that Does i require connectionFactory.setAlwaysSessionAsync(true);..

Comment: @AshishAgarwal from the documentation setAlwaysSessionAsync seems to be true by default

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I send code in Answer because limitation in StatckOverflow comment. Can you please take a look as my problem is not solved.